# Auto delete previous / old events from iOS 7 Calendar?

Tags: calendar, iphone, ios

I don't like to keep old events (of previous week or month) in my iPhone calendar, but they keep up showing in my iOS Calendar, I want them gone automatically as the event passes. I don't want to delete each passed event manually. Is there any way that my events get deleted automatically as the new day or week begins ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two things you can do about this, one on the device and one on [iCloud.com](http://www.icloud.com):

- On the device, you can setup to sync the calendar only for the events in the past two weeks (that's the shortest duration in the past you can set it to).

  1. Do this by going to **Settings** → **Mail, Contacts, Calendars**
  2. Under the **Calendars** section, go to the **Sync** submenu
  3. Select **Events 2 Weeks Back**
- Login to [iCloud.com](http://www.icloud.com), go to Calendar and follow Apple's help on "[Delete or hide events](http://help.apple.com/icloud/#/mmfbbb4470)":

  > To automatically hide past events, choose Preferences from the Action pop-up menu [image], click Advanced, select “Hide events *n*-days after they’ve passed,” then enter a number of days.

  Set it to 1 day (that's the minimum allowed).